# How do I create a Builder that can build more than one kind of Java object?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I’m trying to create a kind of `Multi Strategy Builder`. I mean this builder should be generalized and should have different method depends on entity type. Let me explain it.

Depends on entity we need to have different methods. Examples:

```
Builder<User> userBuilder;
userBuilder.withName(«Bob»);
userBuilder.withAge(17);
```

and this builder must have no others method!

```
Builder<Account> accountBuilder;
accountBuilder.withCounry(«Fr»);
accountBuilder.withNumber(2846218354);
accountBuilder.withCode(«X34»);
```

What pattern should I use? And how to organize my design?

Comment: Is  this possible in Java? I don't know about Java 8 but with Java <= 7 I don't think this is possible. To be honest if you check this link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle, then, I would argue that you should create a unique builder for each type. If you think about it, it won't lead to code duplication since if you have a type User, then a type Admin which extends User, then the Admin builder can extend the User builder and hence, no code duplication.

Comment: I would go `UserBuilder` and `AccountBuilder`. Much clearer, and you dont gain anything via parameterized types, I dont think it is even possible tbh.

Comment: If a custom Java agent is an option for you, you can have a look at project Lombok and the `@Builder` annotation: http://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Builder.html

Comment: Could you use Groovy ? If yes you can do something similar to the dynamic finder in Gorm (Grails). It uses a mix of methods added at runtime with a descriptor that is used by IDEs for the autocompletion...

Comment: @vikingsteve Yes it's well known solution. When you have a bunch of builders and one factory.

Comment: @Guillaume No, I couldn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible for generic interface to have different methods depending on passed to it class in Java. This means that `Builder` interface can have either:

- `withName` and `withAge` methods
- `withCountry`, `withNumber` and `withCode` methods
- all of them

There is no design pattern that can overcome Java language limitations. What I would advise is to have generic builder interface like:

```
public interface Builder<T> {
    T build();
}
```

and then create separate subclasses for each entity type:

```
public class UserBuilder implements Builder<User> {

     public void withName(String name) {
         // ...
     }

     public void withAge(int age) {
         // ...
     }

     public User build() {
         User user = new User();
         user.setName(...);
         user.setAge(...);
         return user;
     }

}

public class AccountBuilder implements Builder<Account> {

    public void setCountry(String country) {
         // ...
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
         // ...
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
         // ...
    }

    public Account build() {
         Account account = new Account();
         account.setCountry(...);
         account.setNumber(...);
         account.setCode(...);
         return account;
    }
}
```

and then use it like

```
UserBuilder userBuilder = new UserBuilder();
userBuilder.setName("John");
userBuilder.setAge(20);
User user = userBuilder.build();

AccountBuilder accountBuilder = new AccountBuilder();
accountBuilder.setCountry("UA");
accountBuilder.setNumber("333-22-1");
accountBuilder.setCode("123");
```

And that's it. This can be slightly improved by using [Fluent Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) pattern but anyway in Java it's **impossible** to implement it to work exactly like in your question.

Hope this helps...

Comment: "It's impossible to implement it to work exactly like in your question." ⇒ It's actually not _impossible_. A custom class-loader could do it. But it wouldn't be easy (and depending on how far you go with it, what you wind up with might not be considered Java anymore).

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting - then I welcome you to answer following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25920002/can-parameterized-generic-class-instance-have-different-methods-depending-on-typ :)

Answer (score 4):

If you're asking for a single `Builder` type that doesn't need to know anything about the entities it operates on, Java can't easily do it the way you describe. In the `Builder<User>` example, the `withName` and `withAge` methods would need to be known at compile-time.

Since those methods don't actually exist, but would need to be dynamically added, you'd have to write a custom class-loader. Once the `Builder` class is linked, you can't change it, and since it doesn't know what methods you want until you pass in an entity, it's too late to change at the point you need to add methods.

You could get mostly there by using reflection. For instance, you could have a single method in `Builder` called, say, `with(String field, Class<?> c, Object value)`. Then, assuming the object instance you're building has a method named "set___", you can use the [`Method`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html) class to invoke the corresponding set method with the value that was passed in.

That would look something like:

```
 Builder<Account> b = new Builder<>();
 b.with("AccountNumber", String.class, "5897-1048-2949");
     // this invokes "setAccountNumber" method on internal
     //   Account instance with "5897-1048-2949" cast to String
```

A better idea is to have classes for thing you're going to build: `AccountBuilder`, `UserBuilder`, and so on. This is clearer and is probably the best you can do in Java without resorting to exotic solutions like custom class-loaders. (Yes, you'll have to write the properties for each one.)

But if you decide you need to do a lot of building, you may want to consider an alternative language that makes this easier to pull off, like [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/) or [Elixir](http://elixir-lang.org/). Dynamic methods are not Java's strong suit, and trying to circumvent a language's limitations just to achieve a particular API is generally a terrible idea.

Comment: It's no user friendly solution. Plus it's Reflection API, so it's slow.

Comment: When I was asking my question I assumed some Design Pattern solution.

Comment: @Alex "It's no user friendly solution. Plus it's Reflection API, so it's slow." ⇒ Well, as I said, you're not going to easily get this without switching to a different language. Dynamic methods are not Java's strong suit.

Comment: This answer is the correct one. But it is forcing Java to be something it is not. +1 for being able to show a solution but this code should never be used. DRY (don't repeat yourself) shouldn't be taken to an extreme, two builders for two different things is *not* code duplication.

Answer (score 1):

First, adding dynamic methods is not very java like.

Builder is a creational pattern and strategy is behavioural. I would not mix them here.

Builder will create objects of a given TYPE. Do your USER and Account have a same type? IMO, unlike other design patterns books, the GoF book very effectively explains what a type of an object is. Do read the discussion. Given the code snippets, I wouldn't say user and account have same type. I would use different builders for building the objects of user and account. The type discussion will come in handy for strategy as well.