# Can parameterized generic class instance have different methods depending on type argument?

Tags: java, generics, classloader

While answering following question:
[How do I create a Builder that can build more than one kind of Java object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25912679/how-do-i-create-a-builder-that-can-build-more-than-one-kind-of-java-object) I thought that it's impossible to achieve the following in Java:

```
public class Builder<T> {
     // ...
}

Builder<User> userBuilder = new Builder<User>();
// here userBuilder only has method 'name'
userBuilder.name("John");

Builder<Country> countryBuilder = new Builder<Country>();
// here countryBuilder only has method 'code'
countryBuilder.code("UA");
```

But, in the comments, user [John Feminella](https://stackoverflow.com/users/75170/john-feminella) told that it is actually possible using custom class loaders.

Now, I know basics of class loaders in Java, but really have no idea how they can alter Java syntax. Could someone give basic idea on how this can be achieved?

Thanks in advance!

P.S. No need for long code snippets - short explanation using standard terms would do.

Comment: John said it was possible, but wouldn't be easy.  I'll add that it's so complicated I doubt I could sketch out how it would function.  Just use the example he was replying to as the correct answer, there's no way you'd want to do anything like your code above.

Comment: I'm not sure you could make this compile, TBH -- custom classloaders wouldn't do the job; you need some compile-time magic, and I'm still not convinced it's possible.

Comment: What you'd really want to do is just make a factory method: `Builder<Country> b = Builders.getBuilder( Builder.class )`.  But even then I think the type parameter is more hindrance than help.

Comment: Yes, I also thought that I need to use some `compile-time magic`, but comment stating that it's possible using custom class loaders really interested me so I asked this question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it's hard is because Java's built-in classloader will not reload a class once it's been added, and reloading a class is required (in Java) to add methods dynamically. Furthermore, the `ClassLoader.resolve()` method is `final`, meaning a custom class loader can't override it. This has a number of effects, but the most important one is that if you want to reload a class, you *must* instantiate a new `ClassLoader` every time you want to load it.

That's enormously expensive, so there's really no practical reason to try and work around the limitations of Java this way. (You should be using another language more suited to this sort of work, like JRuby.) Dynamically loading things is possible, but it's just not worth it.

But, assuming you're willing to suffer some pain, can you do it? Absolutely. See, e.g., [this article](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071777/design-patterns/add-dynamic-java-code-to-your-application.html). The strategy used there is to:

- compile Java code at runtime
- load/reload Java class at runtime via a proxy class
- link the up-to-date class to its caller

Comment: Ok, so this includes compiling Java code at runtime - I thought this can be achieved without that i.e. using only custom class loaders :) Anyway, thanks for your time!